# How do I remove role="search" from the form-tag in drupal?

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal. I have developed one site . But in WCAG 2.0 testing I was getting following problem: **Element 'form' does not need a 'role' attribute.** How do I achive this ? Please Help...

Thanks.

Here is my source code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khTWw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x). You need to try this code with your custom module.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form["#attributes"]["role"] = ""; 
    //Or
    unset($form["#attributes"]["role"]);
  }
}
```

You need to create a custom module at 'sites/all/modules' directory and in the .module file you need to write this function replacing the hook with module name.

For example, create a custom module with the name custom. See [this article](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules) if needs help. In the modules's custom.module file write the following function:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form["#attributes"]["role"] = ""; 
    //Or
    unset($form["#attributes"]["role"]);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. but it did not work for me. I have update this lines in modules/system/system.api.php file in the you mentioned function.

Comment: I have edited the answer that might help!. You first need to create a custom module and then use the hooks. You are editing at the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My issue is solved.
Thank You so much.